# kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KotlinReflectionInternalError when running a native image with Spring Cloud Gateway and Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I've successfully generated a native image of a Spring Cloud Gateway (2022.0.0 - Spring Boot 3.0.0) application implemented in Kotlin.

I have the following security configuration:

```
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
class SecurityConfiguration(private val clientService: ClientService,
                            private val env: Environment) {

    @Bean
    fun springSecurityFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        return http.requestCache {
            it.requestCache(NoOpServerRequestCache.getInstance())
        }.headers { headers ->
            headers.frameOptions { frameOptions ->
                frameOptions.disable()
            }
        }.csrf { it.disable() }
                .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())
                .addFilterAt(basicAuthenticationFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.HTTP_BASIC)
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
                ...
                .and()
                .build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
        return createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()
    }

    private fun basicAuthenticationFilter(): AuthenticationWebFilter {
        val authManager = ApiAuthenticationManager(clientService)
        val apiAuthenticationFilter = AuthenticationWebFilter(authManager)
        return apiAuthenticationFilter
    }

}
```

When I run the native image it crashes with the following exception:

```
kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KotlinReflectionInternalError: Could not compute caller for function: private open fun basicAuthenticationFilter(): org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter defined in xxx.configuration.SecurityConfiguration[DeserializedSimpleFunctionDescriptor@3ff718f] (member = null)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KFunctionImpl$caller$2.invoke(KFunctionImpl.kt:88)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KFunctionImpl$caller$2.invoke(KFunctionImpl.kt:61)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazyVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:63)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:32)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KFunctionImpl.getCaller(KFunctionImpl.kt:61)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.ReflectJvmMapping.getJavaMethod(ReflectJvmMapping.kt:63)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.ReflectJvmMapping.getKotlinFunction(ReflectJvmMapping.kt:136)
        at org.springframework.core.MethodParameter$KotlinDelegate.getGenericReturnType(MethodParameter.java:914)
        at org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getGenericParameterType(MethodParameter.java:510)
        at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper$MethodParameterTypeProvider.getType(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:291)
        at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper.forTypeProvider(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:107)
        at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forType(ResolvableType.java:1413)
        at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1334)
        at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1316)
        at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1283)
        at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodReturnType(ResolvableType.java:1228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:814)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:681)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:652)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1632)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:559)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:531)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:106)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:745)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:565)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
        at xxx.GatewayApplicationKt.main(GatewayApplication.kt:27)

Exception in thread "main" kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KotlinReflectionInternalError: Could not compute caller for function: private open fun basicAuthenticationFilter(): org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter defined in xxx.configuration.SecurityConfiguration[DeserializedSimpleFunctionDescriptor@3ff718f] (member = null)
```

This call `.addFilterAt(basicAuthenticationFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.HTTP_BASIC)`, that refers to a private function seems to be involving some kind of Kotlin refection.

Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: Try using the `RuntimeHintsRegistrar` to register a custom hint. You can register the `basicAuthenticationFilter` for reflections using `hints.reflection().registerMethod(ReflectionUtils.findMethod(SecurityConfiguration.class, "basicAuthenticationFilter"), ExecutableMode.INVOKE)`. See the custom hints [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html#native-image.advanced.custom-hints).

Comment: It worked. If you add your comment as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security uses reflection to get the class of a custom filter, in order to keep track of the order in the filter chain.

To run the code as a native image a reflection hint is needed to tell GraalVM that the private method `basicAuthenticationFilter` needs to be available in the native image.

You can add [custom hints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html#native-image.advanced.custom-hints) using the `RuntimeHintsRegistrar`. In this case you can register `basicAuthenticationFilter` for reflection using:

```java
public class MyRuntimeHints implements RuntimeHintsRegistrar {

    @Override
    public void registerHints(RuntimeHints hints, ClassLoader classLoader) {
        Method method = ReflectionUtils.findMethod(SecurityConfiguration.class, "basicAuthenticationFilter"
        hints.reflection().registerMethod(method, ExecutableMode.INVOKE);
    }

}
```